# How do I select the text within this element in jsoup?

Tags: html, jsoup

EDIT: The website is http://www.op.gg/statistics/champion/

I am trying to select the text withing the element highlighted in gray in this photo: https://i.gyazo.com/cc31794574692e2bc6709e193b27741c.png

I've tried the following plus some other variations but none seem to work.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.op.gg/statistics/champion/").get();
String s = "";
s += doc.select("table.StatisticsChampionTable.sortable.tablesorter.tablesorter-default 
.Content .Row.Top .Cell.ChampionName a").text();
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you can provide the site to check the page

Comment: You are right, the site is this: http://www.op.gg/statistics/champion/

Comment: and how do you retrieve the page via jsoup?

Comment: Edited into post

Comment: get alone could not retrieve the data you need

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
doc.select(".StatisticsChampionTable .ChampionName a").text()
```

Maybe [this](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) could help you next time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may helps you.

You have to scrap the data with the combination of WebView and Jsoup.

First of all load the webpage in the webview and put the webview visibility invisible or gone. And than parse the HTML string into the JSoup.Than you can easily find that all tags which you needed and here is the example code as per your requirement.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Handler handlerForJavascriptInterface = new Handler();
    private WebView mWebView;
    private String mURL = "http://www.op.gg/statistics/champion/";
    private String html_source;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.wv);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(MainActivity.this), "HtmlViewer");
        mWebView.loadUrl(mURL);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // Page loading started
            }


            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                        "('&lt;html&gt;'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'&lt;/html&gt;');");
            }
        });
    }

    class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        private Context ctx;

        MyJavaScriptInterface(Context ctx) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showHTML(final String html) {
            //code to use html content here
            handlerForJavascriptInterface.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    html_source = html;
                    new Description().execute();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private class Description extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document mBlogDocument = Jsoup.parse(html_source);

            int mPaginationSize = mBlogDocument.select("td[class=Cell ChampionName]").size();

            for (int page = 0; page < mPaginationSize; page++) {

                String mChampionName = mBlogDocument.select("td[class=Cell ChampionName]").eq(page).text();

                Log.i("Champion Name " + page, mChampionName + "\n");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set description into TextView
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class Snippet {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.op.gg/statistics/ajax2/champion/").get();

        List<Element> links = doc.select("table > tbody > tr > .Cell.ChampionName > a");
        for (Element link : links) {
            System.out.println(link.absUrl("href"));
        }

    }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
http://www.op.gg/champion/Taric/
http://www.op.gg/champion/Quinn/
http://www.op.gg/champion/Kled/
http://www.op.gg/champion/Draven/
http://www.op.gg/champion/MonkeyKing/
http://www.op.gg/champion/Yorick/
http://www.op.gg/champion/Zilean/
http://www.op.gg/champion/Zyra/
http://www.op.gg/champion/Morgana/
http://www.op.gg/champion/Singed/
http://www.op.gg/champion/Nocturne/
http://www.op.gg/champion/Nami/
http://www.op.gg/champion/Udyr/
```